# 504 Gateway Time-out when trying to login to laravel project

Tags: networking, laravel-5, server, load-balancing, haproxy

I have a laravel v5.2 project, My pc environment is ubnuntu (host)

The project is on vms, the vm configuration is like below :

There is an haproxy to load two relplica sets which they are also ubuntu vms.

project is on my pc home directory which I've shared it over this replica sets. 
Each requests goes to haproxy and then it will load balance requests to those two replica sets.

haproxy network configuration is bridge (static ip) to be reachable to other users in the network.

those two replica sets network configurations are NAT for talking to haproxy only.

I had no problem using this configuration but after I change my internet connection of my pc I can't login to my project any more while I updated all ip address's and configurations, and when I try to login to my project I get :

```
504 Gateway Time-out

The server didn't respond in time.
```

The strange part is When I try to reach for example user info with manually created token : there is no problem and I can get user info data or any other routes data.

The problem is just **login,register routes**. which I didn't have this problem when I was using my previous internet connection.

I describe my vm and network configurations below :

My pc(host) network configuration :

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
        address 192.168.30.245
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.30.0
        gateway 192.168.30.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

My pc(host) /etc/hosts :

```
192.168.30.236  api.project.local
```

The HAproxy vm network :

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.30.236
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.30.0
broadcast 192.168.30.255
gateway 192.168.30.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static

address 192.168.100.113
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.100.0
broadcast 192.168.100.255
gateway 10.0.2.15
```

The Replica set A network :

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static

address 192.168.100.110
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.100.0
broadcast 192.168.100.255
gateway 10.0.2.15
```

The replica set B network :

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static

address 192.168.100.110
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.100.0
broadcast 192.168.100.255
gateway 10.0.2.15
```

Mysql and mongodb servers are on my local pc(host) which it's ip is : `192.168.30.245`

And as I said there is no problem connecting to mysql or mongodb servers from other `routes` or `artisan tinker`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem, The problem was due to my network change and change of gateway.

for anyone that has this kind of network configuration, they should know that if you have a load balancer and two pair of replica sets you have to define same gateway for all of them which it can be modem or router, to be able to resolve each server and os and also mysql and mongodb engines.

if you notice I have defined same gateway for all of those server but because it's direct wireless from isp and dhcp enabled from isp this servers couldn't resolve each other because they would go through NAT which It was also on the isp side.